# How to get all error messages on a custom registration form in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I have a custom registration form courtesy of [this](https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-separate-login-registration/) tutorial, however; if I leave all mandatory fields blank, it appears that I only get one error at a time which is annoying e.g. If try to submit my form without email, name, and surname; the only error I get is about the email and only after I resolve the email error do I get other errors and I have to work through them one by one, is there a way that I can just validate the whole form instead of field by field? I suspect that I get this behaviour because of the returns in the [wc_create_new_customer](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-user-functions.php#L41) function

Answer (score 1):

Found a way around the issue, and I am just going to answer this for anyone walking through the valley of the shadow of death, what I ended up doing was using the `woocommerce_process_registration_errors` filter which I can use to validate all registration fields and add all errors in one go, I proceeded to copy some of the validations from `wc_create_new_customer` in `wc_user_functions` like so

`add_filter('woocommerce_process_registration_errors',  'validate_registration_fields', 10, 4 );`

```
function validate_registration_fields($errors, $unsername, $password, $email) {

  // Email empty wc-form-handler and wc-user-functions
  if ( empty( $email ) || ! WC_Validation::is_email( $email ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'registration-error-invalid-email', __( 'Please provide a valid email address.', 'woocommerce' ) );
  }

  // Email exists
  if ( email_exists( $email ) ) {
    $errors->add( 'registration-error-email-exists', __( 'An account is already registered with your email address. Please log in.', 'woocommerce' ) );
  }

  // more validation code here

  return $errors;
}
```